# Bleaching of chlorophyll stains using hydrogen peroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, enzymes

I have been doing some experiments concerning bleaching of chlorophyll stains from cotton clothing. Currently I have found that $\ce{H2O2}$ is fairly effective, but still leaves visible stains. Would a crude [Horseradish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseradish) root extract containing peroxidase get me better results?

The reason I'm asking about the crude extract and not the purified enzyme is because I don't have access to a laboratory or more complex materials and my work also aims to produce simple methods of chlorophyll degradation that could be replicated at home.

Comment: Chlorophyll is not well soluble in water.  Since your cotton clothing might have been dyed *prior* to the unwanted exposure to chlorophyll, you could try th following cleaning agents first at a spot less visible and if they do not remove your clothing colors, apply them on the stain:  a) vinegar, or b) pure alcohol, or c) some of luke-warm water + bile / gall soap brushed over the stain and allowed to sit there four an hour at ambient conditions prior to a normal wash.  By own experience, if you know there were stains there, you will be more likely to see them even if others do not spot them.

Answer (score 3):

Horseradish peroxidase is not hydrogen peroxide, $\ce{H2O2}$, but rather an enzyme that *breaks* $\ce{H2O2}$ into $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$. In general, enzymes ending in -ase are [lytic enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysis), catalyzing the breakdown of a similar-sounding substance. So, if you add ground horseradish to hydrogen peroxide, bubbles of oxygen are released. BTW, horseradish roots differ in peroxidase potency, so test beforehand with a particular batch before doing this as a demonstration... sometimes it fizzles out, or not.

Another example of lytic enzyme, [amylase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylase) in the mouth, breaks apart [amylose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylose) in starch, so a starchy cracker tastes sweeter as it melts in your mouth.

As @Buttonwood suggests, [alcohols, ether and oils](https://www.scribd.com/document/138557792/Chlorophyll-pdf) are more effective solvents than water.

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{H2O2}$ is Selective

The reason why hydrogen peroxide can be used for such diverse applications is the different ways in which its power can be directed -- termed selectivity. By simply adjusting the conditions of the reaction (*e.g.*, $\mathrm{pH}$, temperature, dose, reaction time, and/or catalyst addition), $\ce{H2O2}$ can often be made to oxidize one pollutant over another, or even to favor different oxidation products from the same pollutant. 
(From http://www.h2o2.com/products-and-services/us-peroxide-technologies.aspx?pid=112)

You might try mixing 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ with vinegar, ~1/1, or with $\ce{Na2CO3}$ (washing soda), and applying these materials to first, a small test spot, and then the stain. Many times, alkali will solubilize contaminants that aren't easily oxidized - and perhaps addition of a little surface-active agent, like dishwasher soap, can assist removal of oleophilic stains. Some commercial pre-wash stain removers also contain butyl ethers as solvent and surface tension reducer.

And if the clothing is white, there is always chlorine bleach (sodium hypochlorite)!